# How do I combine django querys to allow me to save in one go?

Tags: django, django-models

As it stands, I have a deserialiser that can import any model I throw at it and put it into my database. unfortunately it hits the database with every single model and I want to stop this.

Is there any way for me to lump lots of short saves into one big one?

Example code:

```
def deserialise(xml):
    for x in model_list:
         do work to make instance...
         instance.save()
    return True
```

is there any way to move the saving of instance out of the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`transaction.commit_manually()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually).

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def deserialise(xml):
    for x in model_list:
         # do work to make instance...
         instance.save()
    transaction.commit()
    return True
```

Or [`transaction.commit_on_success()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/?from=olddocs#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) which will automatically commit the saves when and if the function returns successfully.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def deserialise(xml):
    for x in model_list:
         # do work to make instance...
         instance.save()
    return True
```

---

Alternatively, in django 1.4 there's also [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create), but do note the caveats listed in  documentation.

Comment: Excellent answer :) i had no idea i could do that!